# How to write apache rewrite mode for html?

Tags: html, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

When someone enter `http://ww.mysite.com/share.html/abcdef` then url should be keep same as `http://ww.mysite.com/share.html/abcdef`

but it should be processed as `http://ww.mysite.com/share.html?q=abcdef`
on server.

I have tried below existing solution but it gives me 404 not found error,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^share.html/(.*)$ share.html?q=$1 [QSA]
```

Comment: Try adding the `/` in your rule. RewriteRule ^share.html/(.*)$ share.html/?q=$1 [QSA]

Comment: still give me 404 not found

Comment: without the rule you can you get to the `share.html` ?

Comment: "http://example.com/share.html?q=VpsTOrfE" this working url

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line :

```
RewriteRule ^share.html/(.*)$ share.html?q=$1 [QSA]
```

With this :

```
RewriteRule ^share\.html/(.*)$ share.html?q=$1 [L]
```

First you should escape `.` and also add `L` flag .

**NOTE:** `QSA` flag has no meaning in your case, read this https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html